# How to find number of ways of permuting a string satisfying the below conditions?

Tags: combinations, permutation, combinatorics

I am given a string,let say- **"abcd"**.
Now I have to find all the strings that can be generated by permuting its character such that-

> 1. There are exactly four mismatches in the generated strings and,
> 2. The mismatches exists in pair, for e.g-

The string - **"abcd"** has three such permutations-
**"badc"**,**"cdab"**,**"dcba"**.

**Explanation-**

Let us consider **"abcd"** and **"badc"**. Now there are exactly four mismatch with , i.e- **(a,b)**,**(b,a)**,**(c,d)**,**(d,c)** and these mismatches exists in pair.

Note that **"abcde"** has fifteen such permutations-
**acbed**,**adebc**,**aedcb**,**baced**,**badce**,**baedc**,**cbaed**,**cdabe**,**ceadb**,**dbeac**,**dcbae**,**decab**,**ebdca**,**ecbda**,**edcba**

**Where I am failing?**-

I am just finding the strings manually, but this becomes really time-consuming for strings of large length. Hence,I need a efficient solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a string of length `n`, consisting of `n` different letters, then the number you are finding is: `n * (n - 1) * (n - 2) * (n - 3) / 8`.

Reason: there are `C(n, 4)` ways to choose `4` mismatch places from `n` letters, and for every such quadruple, there are three ways to pair them.

Hence the result is `C(n, 4) * 3 = n * (n - 1) * (n - 2) * (n - 3) / 8`.

---

Here the hypothesis is that all letters in the string are different. It is unclear from your description of problem whether letters can repeat. Please comment on this answer if this is your case. I will then update the answer.

---

Edit: Now suppose that the letters can repeat. The situation is more complicated. I will just give sketches here.

Let's say the string contains `m` different letters, occurring `a_1, ..., a_m` times, respectively. Also, write `b_i` for the number `C(a_i, 2)`.

There are three cases:

- Case 1: the four mismatches form two identical pairs, e.g. two **a**'s and two **b**'s are permuted.

In this case, we have `sum{b_i * b_j : 1 <= i < j <= m}` different strings. This is equal to `(sum{b_i}^2 - sum{b_i ^2}) / 2`, an expression that can be evaluated in `O(m)` time.

- Case 2: the four mismatches contain three different letters, e.g. one **a** is paired with one **b**, and another **a** is paired with one **c**.

In this case, first choose the letter that is common in the two pairs, let's say it's the `i`-th letter; then one has to choose the other two letters.

Write `s` for the sum of all `a_i`, and `t` for the sum of all `b_i`. If we choose two arbitrary letter from the remaining `s - a_i` letters, we have to exclude cases where the two letters are identical, which has `t - b_i` possibilities. Thus there are `C(s - a_i, 2) - (t - b_i)` different ways to choose the other two letters, hence `b_i * (C(s - a_i, 2) - (t - b_i))` different strings. Summing them up for all `i` gives the total number of different strings in this case. It still can be evaluated in `O(m)` time.

- Case 3: four different letters, e.g. one **a** and one **b** form a pair, and one **c** and one **d** form another pair.

The idea is the same. First, consider the possibilities of choosing `4` arbitrary letters from all `s` letters. Then we have to exclude several cases:

i. All four letters are identical, this has `sum{C(a_i, 4)}` cases;

ii. Three letter are identical, the fourth is different, this has `sum{C(a_i, 3) * (s - a_i)}` cases;

iii. Two letters are identical, the other two are also identical, this is exactly the number calculated in Case 1;

iv. Two letters are identical, the other two are different, this is exactly the number calculated in Case 2.

So, the total number of possibilities of choosing four different letters from all `s` letters is: `C(s, 4) - [i] - [ii] - [iii] - [iv]`. As before, this number should be multiplied by `3` to yield the number of different strings, because each quadruple gives `3` different strings.

All in all, the time complexity is `O(m)`, which is obviously optimal.

Comment: Yes, actually I want to derive a formula for the case when the letters are repeating,say- "abbc".

Comment: Will you be able to post another detailed explanation(as you did for above) for a string containing repeating letters also(it would be preferable if you will take an example like- abbbbcccdeff). It will be very much helpful.

Comment: Finally, understood it(the key to solving this problem is-"inclusion-exclusion" which is one of my weak areas in combinatorics). Seems, like you are having a very strong control in the area of combinatorics. Finally, the last question that I am facing problem is- [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1694022/how-to-find-number-of-strings-generated-by-permuting-the-given-string-satisfying) Will you be able to give another good explanation? Thanks,for your efforts till now

Comment: That problem is almost the same (even easier). You can apply the same technique (inclusion-exclusion). First look at any three of the twelve letters, which gives `C(12, 3)` possibilities; then exclude two cases: 1. all three letters are identical; 2. two of them are identical, and the third is different. I think this should be enough as a hint.

Comment: Yes, I tried to solve it using inclusion and exclusion. But I am not getting the correct answer. The correct answer is 260.
Can you come up with a detailed generalised explanation?